# Trouble making asynchronous mocha tests with async/await

Tags: asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, async-await, mocha.js

I am using mocha and selenium-webdriver for E2E tests. Most of the tests are async and I am using async/await functions to handle this. Unfortunately right now I can't get a single one done. Here is what my code looks like:

```
describe('Some test', function () {
  before(function () {
    driver.navigate().to('http://localhost:3000')
  })

  after(function () {
    driver.quit()
  })

  it('should display element', async function () {
    let elementFound = false
    try {
      await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.className('element'))), 1000)
      assessForm = await driver.findElement(By.className('element')).isDisplayed()
      assert.ok(elementFound)
      console.log('elementFound', elementFound)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      assert.fail(err)
    }
  })
})
```

The problem that is happening seems to be that the `after` function is being called before the test can finish. Here are the error logs:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>
> { NoSuchSessionError: no such session   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.36.540469
>   (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3
>   x86_64)
>       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/me./myproject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
>       at parseHttpResponse (/Users/me./myproject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:533:13)
>       at Executor.execute (/Users/me./myproject/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) name: 'NoSuchSessionError', remoteStacktrace: '' }

If I remove my `after()` function, I still get

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

but, my console.log shows that my element has been found.

If I then try making `after()` async, like this:

```
  after(async function () {
    await driver.quit()
  })
```

I get the same error as the first one.

It is also important to note that I have read that I don't have to use `done()` when I am doing async/await. So what in the world is that all about? And even if I did, I keep getting the same error.

How do I solve this? It seems like everything is in order, but I can't seem to appropriately  have the tests run through without running into each other.

Comment: When does your console.log show that your element has been found? Before or after the timeout error?

Comment: It could be your `before` function should be async too so that tests will start only after navigation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.className('element'))), 1000)
```

try:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('element'))).isDisplayed()
```